# [NSURLSessionDataTask response]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, exception

I have the following issue:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURLSessionDataTask response]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fced8599e60'

This is where it comes from:

```
GET("users/check_email", parameters: parameters, progress: nil, success: { sessionDataTask, response in

    //the line with error
    let statusCode = (sessionDataTask.response as? NSHTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode ?? 0
        
    completionBlock(self.queryType?.mockStatusCode ?? statusCode, nil)
        
    }) { sessionDataTask, error in
            
        completionBlock(nil, NSError(responseError: error))
}
```

This happens when I try to mock a response. At some place of code I pass to `success` block:

```
var sessionDataTask = NSURLSessionDataTask()
success?(sessionDataTask, queryType?.mockResponse())
```

Something is wrong with `sessionDataTask`. `NSURLSessionDataTask` inherits from `NSURLSessionTask` which has `response` property. I don't know why I get this error.

Comment: place the breackpoint on the " statusCode = (sessionDataTask.response as? NSHTTPURLResponse)?..." line  and check the sessionDataTask object type.

Comment: `po sessionDataTask` returns `<NSURLSessionDataTask: 0x7f9ca9d1d4e0>`

Comment: Check ... correct argument is coming or not ?

Comment: Be more clarify, do not understand what you mean.

Comment: The handler gives you sessionDataTask and response, try use response instead of sessionDataTask in (sessionDataTask.response as? NSHTTPURLResponse)?

Comment: @Greg no, it is not that, because, `response` is a response from server, opposite to  `sessionDataTask.response` which is a http response. This is where i can get `statusCode` from.

Comment: @Igor when I print `po sessionDataTask.response` then I get the info: `[NSURLSessionDataTask response]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffb8bc63050
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: internal ObjC exception breakpoint(-3)..`

Answer (score 2):

If you declare your mock NSURLSessionDataTask like below, response will be nil.

Obj C:

```
NSURLSessionDataTask * sessionDataTask = [[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]] dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
[sessionDataTask response];
```

Swift:

```
var sessionDataTask = NSURLSessionDataTask(NSURLSession(sessionWithConfiguration:NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()).dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: "")))
sessionDataTask.response()
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple documentation says:

```
public class NSURLSessionTask : NSObject, NSCopying {
    @NSCopying public var response: NSURLResponse? { get } /* may be nil if no response has been received */
}
```

So the only solution for this in Swift is:

```
var statusCode = 0

if sessionDataTask.respondsToSelector(Selector("response")) {
    statusCode = (sessionDataTask.response as? NSHTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode ?? 0
}
```